# A lookaround regex to find html tags without both attributes

Tags: html, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I need a regex to search some HTML and find all `<img>` tags that have this attribute : `class="lazy"` and not that one : `data-original="..."`.

Here is my sample test markup :

```
<!-- Must match : -->
<img class="lazy" src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1" alt="Lorem ipsum" />
<img class="lazy" src="http://placehold.it/640x360/abd125/fff" />
<img class="lazy" src="http://placehold.it/640x360/000/fff"
alt="Blabla" />

<!-- Must not match : -->
<img class="lazy" src="http://placehold.it/255x200/111/fff&text=loading" data-original="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/255/200/2" width="255" height="200" alt="" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/640x360/111/fff" alt="Blabla" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/640x360/333/fff"
alt="Blabla" />
```

I wrote this : `<img[^>]*class\s*=\s*["']lazy["'][^>]*(?!data-original)[^>]*>`

This is not working since it match the 4th tag and it mustn't.

Can you help me ? Thanks.

P.S. Don't worry dudes, I'm not attempting to [parse html the Cthulhu Way](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/), I just need to find these tags quickly to fix a large amount of web templates, this is a one shot trick...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to somehow fix the lookahead, because if it moves, you can miss the 'fail if match' part, and it might also be a good idea to put the `class='lazy'` in a lookahead as well, and you could perhaps do it like this:

```
<img(?=[^>]*class\s*=\s*(["'])lazy\1)(?![^>]*data-original)[^>]*>
```

That way, you don't have to worry about the order `data-original` and `class='lazy'` appear either.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/zL2pD8)

Answer (score 3):

You have to check the negative lookahead `(?![^>]*data-original)` exactly after the `img` tag.

```
<img(?![^>]*data-original)[^>]*class\s*=\s*["']lazy["'][^>]*>
```